# Strange "Task not serializable" with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my program, I have a method which returns some RDD, let's call it `myMethod` which takes a non-serializable parameter and let the RDD be of the type `Long` (my real RDD is a Tuple type but only contains primitive types).

When I try something like this:

```
val x: NonSerializableThing = ...
val l: Long = ...
myMethod(x, l).map(res => res + l) // myMethod's RDD does NOT include the NonSerializableThing
```

I get `Task not serializable`.

When I replace `res + l` by `res + 1L` (i.e., some constant), it runs.

From the serialization trace, it tries to serialize the `NonSerializableThing` and chokes there, but I double-checked my method and this object never appears in an RDD.

When I try to collect output of `myMethod` directly, i.e. with

```
myMethod(x, l).take(1) foreach println
```

I also get no problems.

The method uses the `NonSerializableThing` to get a (local) Seq of values on which multiple Cassandra queries are made (this is needed because I need to construct the partition keys to query for), like this:

```
def myMethod(x: NonSerializableThing, l: Long): RDD[Long] = {
  val someParam1: String = x.someProperty
  x.getSomeSeq.flatMap(y: OtherNonSerializableThing => {
    val someParam2: String = y.someOtherProperty
    y.someOtherSeq.map(someParam3: String =>
      sc.cassandraTable("fooKeyspace", "fooTable").
      select("foo").
      where("bar=? and quux=? and baz=? and l=?", someParam1, someParam2, someParam3, l).
      map(_.getLong(0))
  }.reduce((a, b) => a.union(b))
}
```

The `getSomeSeq` and `someOtherSeq` return plain non-spark `Seq`s

What I want to achieve is to "union" multiple Cassandra queries.

What could be the problem here?

EDIT, Addendum, as requested by Jem Tucker:

What I have in my class is something like this:

```
implicit class MySparkExtension(sc: SparkContext) {

  def getThing(/* some parameters */): NonSerializableThing = { ... }

  def myMethod(x: NonSerializableThing, l: Long): RDD[Long] = {
    val someParam1: String = x.someProperty
    x.getSomeSeq.flatMap(y: OtherNonSerializableThing => {
      val someParam2: String = y.someOtherProperty
      y.someOtherSeq.map(someParam3: String =>
        sc.cassandraTable("fooKeyspace", "fooTable").
        select("foo").
        where("bar=? and quux=? and baz=? and l=?", someParam1, someParam2, someParam3, l).
        map(_.getLong(0))
    }.reduce((a, b) => a.union(b))
  }
}
```

This is declared in a package object. The problem occurrs here:

```
// SparkContext is already declared as sc
import my.pkg.with.extension._

val thing = sc.getThing(/* parameters */)
val l = 42L
val rdd = sc.myMethod(thing, l)
// until now, everything is OK.
// The following still works:
rdd.take(5) foreach println
// The following causes the exception:
rdd.map(x => x >= l).take(5) foreach println
// While the following works:
rdd.map(x => x >= 42L).take(5) foreach println
```

I tested this entered "live" into a Spark shell as well as in an algorithm submitted via `spark-submit`.

What I now want to try (as per my last comment) is the following:

```
implicit class MySparkExtension(sc: SparkContext) {

  def getThing(/* some parameters */): NonSerializableThing = { ... }

  def myMethod(x: NonSerializableThing, l: Long): RDD[Long] = {
    val param1 = x.someProperty
    val partitionKeys =
      x.getSomeSeq.flatMap(y => {
        val param2 = y.someOtherProperty
        y.someOtherSeq.map(param3 => (param1, param2, param3, l)
      }
    queryTheDatabase(partitionKeys)
  }

  private def queryTheDatabase(partitionKeys: Seq[(String, String, String, Long)]): RDD[Long] = {
    partitionKeys.map(k =>
      sc.cassandraTable("fooKeyspace", "fooTable").
         select("foo").
         where("bar=? and quux=? and baz=? and l=?", k._1, k._2, k._3, k._4).
         map(_.getLong(0))
    ).reduce((a, b) => a.union(b))
  }
}
```

I believe this could work because the RDD is constructed in the method `queryTheDatabase` now, where no `NonSerializableThing` exists.

Another option might be: The `NonSerializableThing` would indeed be serializable, but I pass in the `SparkContext` in there as an implicit constructor parameter. I think if I make this transient, it would (uselessly) get serialized but not cause any problems.

Comment: Plz post`mymethod` or at least its signature.

Comment: I still do not see `def mymethod(...) ... `. 2. Where do your object live, what is their context?

Comment: There was a typo in it. It is corrected now.

Comment: `a.union(b)` operates on `RDD`s, so Spark serializes the whole method. I suggest you do the `union` in a separate method.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That's why I prepare everything before, and only use `a.union(b)` as the last step, but the answer below seems to go in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you replace `l` with `1L` Spark no longer tries to serialize the class with the method / variables in and so the error is not thrown.

You should be able to fix by marking `val x: NonSerializableThing = ...` as transient e.g.

```
@transient
val x: NonSerializableThing = ...
```

This means when the class is serialized this variable should be ignored.

Comment: Is it also possible to declare `x: NonSerialiyableThing` as transient when it is passed-in via a parameter? Or would it be enough if I did `@transient val x1: NonSerializableThing = x` and use `x1` from then on?

Comment: If you mean passed in as a parameter in the class constructer then yes. Can you post the full class def containing this code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because I am not allowed to post company code. I will try the following tomorrow: Construct the `Seq` which contains all the partition keys (only Strings, Longs etc. in there), and pass this (and only this) to a private method that does the Cassandra query on the cluster. I think this could be a feasible workaround because then, when the RDD is constructed, there is no `NonSerializableThing` in the scope.

Comment: I extended my first post a bit to show the structure of the class and some example code where this happens.

Comment: Ah I see, I was thinking the `NonSerializableThing` was a class member.  I tested out transient parameters and they seem to work so I would give that a shot. Just change the method to `def mymethod(@transient n: Non..., l: Long)`

Comment: Okay, nice to hear this. I hope it works for me tomorrow. Otherwise, I'd have to re-think my design.

Comment: Thanks Jem, `@transient` was the solution. I made the `SparkContext` transient everywhere, which got me a step further, but then it tried to serialize `MySparkExtension` choking there - because I passed a private method defined there into a `map` running in `myMethod` on the RDD. I rewrote this temporarily using code duplication (I need the same method elsewhere) but I will move it to a separate case object (the method needs nothing from outside put its parameters and they are all serializable).